# How do I load a file into the python console?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I have some lines of python code that I'm continuously copying/pasting into the python console. Is there a `load` command or something I can run? e.g. `load file.py`

Comment: `import file`.  No `.py` extension.

Comment: When `import file` is used, variables in `file` cannot be accessed.

Comment: Actually, variable can be accessed.  Try `file.variable`.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

For Python 2 give [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=execfile#execfile) a try. (See other answers for Python 3)

```
execfile('file.py')
```

Example usage:
Let's use "copy con" to quickly create a small script file...

```
C:\junk>copy con execfile_example.py
a = [9, 42, 888]
b = len(a)
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.
```

...and then let's load this script like so:

```
C:\junk>\python27\python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> execfile('execfile_example.py')
>>> a
[9, 42, 888]
>>> b
3
>>>
```

Comment: Can you explain your usage of `copy con`? From what I'm reading it's only used to copy files http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm

Comment: He copied from the console (treated as a file) to execfile_example.py. ^Z is end of file. It's just a way to get text into a file without opening an editor.

Comment: See the answer from @Arafangion if you are not yet in the console.

Answer (score 239):

From the man page:

> -i     When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command.  It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.  This can be useful to inspect global variables or a stack trace when a script raises an exception.

So this should do what you want:

```
python -i file.py
```

Comment: This is a great way to go if you are not yet in the console. Thanks for the tip Arafangion

Comment: how does one reload the `file.py` if the file has changed? python3.8+

Comment: The question was clearly to load the file when already in the console.

Comment: @RichieHH: A full decade of stack overflow visitors have found it a useful answer, however, and the original question might have been ambiguous and has since been edited...

Comment: @Asalle: For your question, you should put that up as a separate question, however take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410419/python-reload-file

Answer (score 129):

**Python 3: new exec** *(execfile dropped)* **!**

The execfile solution is valid only for Python 2. Python 3 dropped the execfile function - and promoted the exec statement to a builtin universal function. As the comment in Python 3.0's changelog and Hi-Angels comment suggest:

use

```
exec(open(<filename.py>).read())
```

instead of

```
execfile(<filename.py>)
```

Comment: if the file contains import statements e.g. `import os`, does `exec()` execute those statements? I'm trying this currently and the answer appears to be no...

Comment: it should be noted that filename.py is a string and so should be in quotes.  i.e. exec(open("mypythonfile.py").read())

Comment: Well...that's a step backwards.  Thanks, Python 3.

Comment: how do you supply any arguments that the program being executed needs?

Comment: Man that's ugly

Answer (score 35):

From the shell command line:

```
python file.py
```

From the Python command line

```
import file
```

or

```
from file import *
```

Comment: And `reload(file)` when you've changed something in it.

Comment: That's `from file import *`, not `import * from file`

Comment: Does the file need to be a in specific director? I'm trying it with its full path and it's not working.

Comment: import directory.subdirectory.file

Comment: @Seth That's a relative path, isn't it? How about an absolute path?

Answer (score 25):

You can just use an import statement:

```
from file import *
```

So, for example, if you had a file named `my_script.py` you'd load it like so:

```
from my_script import *
```

Comment: what does the * mean?

Comment: The * in this context means to import all names in the script into the current scope. So if you are running this directly from the python command prompt then any variables, functions, etc. that you defined in your script would be available in your python session.

Answer (score 6):

Open command prompt in the folder in which you files to be imported are present. when you type 'python', python terminal will be opened. Now you can use

```
import script_name
```

Note: no .py extension to be used while importing.
 [How can I open a cmd window in a specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904/how-can-i-open-a-cmd-window-in-a-specific-location)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using IPython, you can simply run:

```
%load path/to/your/file.py
```

See http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If your `path` environment variable contains Python (eg. `C:\Python27\`) you can run your py file simply from Windows command line (cmd).
[Howto here.](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables)