# Run Python console after script execution in same environment

Tags: python

Is there a way to execute a Python script, yet stay in the Python shell thereafter, so that variable values could be inspected and such?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is what you want, but you could try using the python debugger [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Comment: The IDLE which ships with Python (you still have to download it on Linux) [has a built-in debugger](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter7.html).

Comment: If you just want to run a Python script and have a REPL afterwards, IDLE is really pretty nice. Just open the file, run it, and then you have the REPL already there.

Comment: Does `execfile` fit what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280178/how-do-i-load-a-file-into-the-python-console

Comment: You can try [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), I like to use this.

Comment: You can [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/) as well.

Comment: I think you are looking for `python -i ./file.py`, where the `-i` flag will enter interactive mode after executing the file.  If you are already in the console, then `execfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaphox nailed it:

> I think you are looking for python -i ./file.py, where the -i flag
>   will enter interactive mode after executing the file. If you are
>   already in the console, then execfile. – Metaphox 2 mins ago

But I want to thank for the other suggestions as well, which go beyond the original question yet are useful!

Answer (score 1):

For those who use IPython you can use the `embed()` function for some extra flexibility since it allows you to drop into a shell anywhere in your program:

```
from IPython import embed

def some_function(args):
    # ... do stuff ...

    embed() # drop to shell here

    # ... back to the function ...
```