# Is there a way to open command prompt in current folder?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a project folder somewhere, and many times I need to open command prompt (on windows 7/8.1/10) and **cd** to that folder. It would be very handy if there's an option **right click > open cmd here.** 
is there a tool for that?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Just go to your folder location and type "cmd" on the address bar.

Comment: without mouse: Ctrl + L = jump to address bar, and after type "cmd"

Comment: You can also use `Alt + D` to switch focus to the address bar.

Comment: but no "elevated" possible :(

Answer (score 6):

Press `Shift + Menu`, then choose `Open Command Window Here`. It works.

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot. can I open it as an administrator?

Comment: Look at this http://superuser.com/questions/453409/how-can-i-always-run-the-command-prompt-as-administrator . Note, you need to alter the register. So, be careful ).

Answer (score 4):

How about to use the PowerShell `OpenHere` [module](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Open-Here-Module)?

Run PowerShell with elevated permissions and type:

```bsh
Install-Module OpenHere; Import-Module OpenHere
Set-OpenHereShortcut -ShortcutType:WindowsPowerShell
```

#### Disclaimer:

I'm a developer of this module.

Answer (score 3):

In win7/8, try right click while holding shift key, should have cmd prompt here

Answer (score 2):

Type cmd command in address bar where path or location of the file or folder is shown.

Answer (score 1):

use the description in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534874/1498669 and put "run as administrator" checkbox on

1. Open 'File Explorer' and enter "shell:sendto" in location bar + hit return to get into this folder
2. Right mouse click and create a "New"->"Shortcut", put cmd.exe into the path, done
3. Edit the properties of the shortcut and edit the target to "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k pushd"
4. you can also create a copy of that shortcut, rename it to cmd.exe_admin, select properties, hit button "Advanced" an select the checkbox "run as Administrator"

Now use the "SendTo"-submenu in the explorer right click context menu to send any filepath or folder into the normal or elevated commandbox.

This "shell:sendto"-trick is also very useful for eg. Notepad++ or any program you want to start in "elevated" mode.