# In Win 10, open command prompt from "Start Menu" -shortcut in a specific folder

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I know how to add command prompt into Windows 10 StartButton_RightClick -menu. 
https://www.askvg.com/tip-restore-command-prompt-shortcut-in-win-x-menu-in-windows-10/

I would like to config shortcut to open cmd.exe in a specific folder, i.e C:\ 
Any ideas?

In addition, how to config cmd.exe window size and colors?

Comment: I think this would be better suited to [superuser](https://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

right click on command prompt icon , select properties there you can set color.[image]

To open cmd prompt in specific folder check this link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904/how-can-i-open-a-cmd-window-in-a-specific-location)

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is done to a shortcut. How to edit properties of Windows Start -menu shortcut? Right-clicking just open command prompt. Edited my question.