# Lilypond to LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex, lilypond

Can someone ELI5 the process? I've tried reading the guide from

http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/an-example-of-a-musicological-document

but it doesn't seem to work. I am on Windows 10, and I have Lilypond 2.18.2 installed. That's everything I've done so far.

Here's what I've tried.

In a text editor, I copy and pasted the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

Documents for \verb+lilypond-book+ may freely mix music and text.
For example,

\begin{lilypond}
\relative c' {
  c2 e2 \tuplet 3/2 { f8 a b } a2 e4
}
\end{lilypond}

Options are put in brackets.

\begin{lilypond}[fragment,quote,staffsize=26,verbatim]
  c'4 f16
\end{lilypond}

Larger examples can be put into a separate file, and introduced with
\verb+\lilypondfile+.

\end{document}
```

Then I saved the file as lilybook.lytex

Then I pressed Start, and type in DOS. Something called a command prompt shows up, and I click it. Then I type in after `C:\Users\[name]>`, starting with a space,

```
lilypond-book --output=out --pdf lilybook.lytex
```

Then, it shows

```
'lilypond-book' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

People at music theory stack exchange have said that it is not for a Windows computer. So how to do this on Windows? Please help, I am very confused. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, it's absolutely nonsense that these tools aren't for Windows. Don't listen to those people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add lilypond-book to your PATH variable just like you possibly did with the lilypond executable. These are the set of instructions from LilyPond's own website:

> Windows on the command line
>
> The most convenient way to run LilyPond is by adding the folder which
>   contains LilyPond executable files to the environmental variable
>   “Path”.
>
> 1. Open your “System” on the Control Panel, select Advanced tab and click Environmental Variables button.
> 2. Select the Variable “Path” from Environmental variables list and click the Edit button. You will be presented a window titled “Edit
>      System Variable”; append to “Variable value” the name of the folder
>      which contains LilyPond executable files like this:
>
>    [pre-set paths];DIR\LilyPond\usr\bin
>
> > Note: DIR will generally be C:\Program Files (x86) for 64 bit or C:\Program Files for 32 bit systems.
>
> and click “OK” button to close the window.
>
> Invoking individual executable files
>
> LilyPond executable files – such as lilypond, lilypond-book,
>   convert-ly, and so on – can be run from the command-line by invoking
>   them:
>
> ```
> lilypond test.ly
> ```

From: http://lilypond.org/windows.html

Comment: Thank you. However, after following those directions, and running `lilypond-book --pdf [name].lytex`, I now get an error. It says that [name].lytex couldn't be found. Do I need to put it in a certain place?

Comment: You need to make sure that your Command Prompt is in the correct directory where your .lytex file is. I am not on Windows but, according to one of the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904/how-can-i-open-a-cmd-window-in-a-specific-location), you can apparently Shift + Right Click on the background of the Explorer window in the directory you want to open, then click on "Open command window here". Else I would recommend you to take a look at these [basic navigation commands](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands).

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: Let me add that nowadays the best tool is [LyLuaTex](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/blob/master/README.en.md). One of the advantages is that you can run LaTeX directly and lilypond snippets will be compiled at the same time.