# How can i run scaffold command from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, command-line, scaffold

How can i run the following command from the code

i have tried the following but not worked

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", @"dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ""server=xxx.xxx.x.xxx;user=xxxxx;database=dbname;port=3306;Password=xxxxx;Allow User Variables=True;"" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -t customers -o ModelsFolderNam");
```

but if i run it in package console then it will scaffold tables succesfully

Comment: When something doesn't work, you need to tell us why it didn't work. Did you get errors? What were they? What output did you expect? What output did you get? Also, why are you trying to run this command via C# in the first place?

Comment: no errors appeared, i need to create an mvc project to scaffold db entities (user-friendly) one

Comment: it's not working for me as well, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because in order to scaffold your context, you have to be in your .NET project path. By default cmd opens in `C:\Users\yourWinUserName>` or if you open cmd directly as administrator that would be: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

Navigate to your project first, then perform scaffold.
Here you can find how to perform that type of navigation in single command:
[How can I open a cmd window in a specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904/how-can-i-open-a-cmd-window-in-a-specific-location)